# Erro no preenchimento automatico

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

`alterar.php`

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
            $("input[name='id']").blur(function(){
                var $serialnum = $("input[name='serialnum']");
                var $validadedata = $("input[name='validadedata']");
                var $descr = $("input[name='descr']");

                $.getJSON('function.php',{ 
                    id: $( this ).val() 
                },function( json ){
                    $serialnum.val( json.serialnum );
                    $validadedata.val( json.validadedata );
                    $descr.val( json.descr );

                });
            });
        });


</script>
```

`function.php`

```
function retorna($id, $conn){
$result_aluno = "SELECT * FROM serialnumbers2 WHERE id = '$id'";
$resultado_aluno = mysqli_query($conn, $result_aluno);
 if($resultado_aluno->num){
    $row_aluno = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_aluno);
    $valores['serialnum'] = $row_aluno['serialnum'];
    $valores['validadedata'] = $row_aluno['validadedata'];
    $valores['descr'] = $row_aluno['descr'];

 }else{
    $valores['serialnum'] = 'Serial não existe';
    $valores['validadedata'] = 'Serial não existe';
    $valores[''] = 'Serial não existe';
 }
}
```

Tudo resulta com o serialnum e a validade data, pois quando meto o id ele vai buscar esses 2 automaticamente, mas não traz a descr, e também está tudo igual, alguem sabe o porque de não ir buscar este campo à BD?

Comment: acho que está faltando código, para podermos te ajudar, por exemplo onde está a sua conexão? e o `return encode_json` na sua função? Por favor poste todo o código para podermos te ajudar melhor.

Comment: A conexão à Bd está correta, o problema tem que estar nestas linhas de código

Comment: Então @fabrício-fonseca eu postei abaixo uma resposta onde no final da `function retorna`, ele retorna uma resposta `json`, vê se te ajuda.

Answer (score 0):

Então Fabrício acredito que na sua função esteja faltando o retorno dela, através do `array` `$valores` passado na função `json_encode()`

```
    function retorna($id, $conn){
        $result_aluno = "SELECT * FROM serialnumbers2 WHERE id = '$id'";
        $resultado_aluno = mysqli_query($conn, $result_aluno);
        $valores = [];

        if($resultado_aluno->num){
            $row_aluno = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_aluno);
            $valores['serialnum'] = $row_aluno['serialnum'];
            $valores['validadedata'] = $row_aluno['validadedata'];
            $valores['descr'] = $row_aluno['descr'];

        }else{
            $valores['serialnum'] = 'Serial não existe';
            $valores['validadedata'] = 'Serial não existe';
            $valores[''] = 'Serial não existe';
        }

        echo json_encode($valores)
}

retorna($id, $conn);
```